# Por que iteração de uma lista com objeto anônimo funciona com array porém não funciona com List<Object>?

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Tentei fazer a seguinte iteração com C#:

```
var objects = List<Object>{
    new {Id = 2, Nome = "Wallace"},
    new {Id = 4, Nome = "Cigano"}
};

foreach (var user in objects) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Meu id é {0}", user.Id);
    Console.WriteLine ("Meu nome é {0}", user.Nome);
}
```

Veja o erro no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CEyrvv)

Deu o seguinte erro:

> Type `object` doesn't not contain a definition for `Id` and not method `Id`  extension could be found.

Porém quando faço isso dá certo:

```
var objects = new []{
    new {Id = 2, Nome = "Wallace"},
    new {Id = 4, Nome = "Cigano"}
};
```

Se o `new {}` é `Object` pensei que não tivesse problema em usar `List<Object>`, porém só consigo fazer essa operação com Array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você está criando uma lista de `Object`. Olhe a [documentação desta classe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Veja se existe os membros `Id` e `Nome` lá na documentação. Não tem. Ele vai aparecer magicamente? Não vai, está usando uma linguagem estaticamente tipada. Então o compilador te diz que não tem isto que você quer usar. Você pode jogar qualquer objeto, inclusive as classes internas criadas para o uso do mecanismo de [*anonymous types*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas na hora de acessar os membros de um objeto qualificado como `object` só poderá acessar os que estão disponíveis no tipo. É a segregação de interface.

Em tese teria uma solução. Faz um *cast* pro tipo real que está colocando dentro da lista e aí ganhará acesso aos membros deste tipo. O problema é que você usou um tipo anônimo (que é uma classe interna que o compilador gera e dá um nome que só ele sabe), e para fazer um *cast* é preciso dizer o nome do tipo que deseja promover. Como você, programador, consegue fazer isto? Não tem jeito.

Então a solução real é criar uma coleção que não precisa especificar o tipo do objeto que ela conterá. Por falha do C# (talvez justificável, não sei dizer, mas consigo ver algum sentido) só o *array* pode fazer isto. Então a solução é usá-lo.

Se precisa mesmo da lista, depois pode converter o *array* para lista que funcionará, porque o compilador se encarregará de tratar tudo o que é necessário e o *cast*, se for preciso, será inserido por ele com o nome que ele mesmo gerou.

O `var` foi criado justamente para isto. Se você mandar imprimir o tipo da variável, será algo assim:

```
<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.String][]
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Kzgjp7). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t6y9uN). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/ScanObject.cs).

Ou se converter para lista:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.String]]
```

Havia até uma [discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30359481#30359481) sobre o uso do [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) para resolver isto. De fato o `dynamic` desliga a verificação do compilador e você pode usar os membros concretos de qualquer objeto existente passando por cima da segurança de tipos do C#. O mesmo vale para o acesso com o uso de *reflection* que te dá acesso a tudo o que quiser sem o compilador ter controle. Isto está filosoficamente errado, é querer fazer o C# virar PHP (a grosso modo), não traz benefício algum e principalmente muda a semântica do que é pedido na pergunta.